# hvvm compiles php code different from php-fpm

Tags: wordpress, nginx, php, hhvm

I have a wordpress instance running on nginx with HHVM and having PHP-FPM as a fallback.

When using HHVM im getting 500 error code with this message:

> \nFatal error: syntax error, unexpected $end in ...

But when I use php-fpm the code compiles just fine. Could be any differences in compiling the code using HHVM and PHP-FPM ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug -- HHVM strives to be fully compatible with PHP5. Please file a bug on the [HHVM issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues), ideally including the full error message, as well as the code that the message referring to. The output of `hhvm --version` and the OS you're running on are also useful to include in the report.

I assume this is some custom code; major frameworks are [well-tested and known to work](http://hhvm.com/frameworks/). In particular for WordPress, http://hhvm.com runs on WordPress+HHVM, so that definitely works :)